# Sufficient syntactic conditions for zero-dimensionality of polynomial systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computer-algebra, groebner-bases

Consider a system $S$ of polynomial equations, $p_1=0,...,p_m=0$, for $p_i\in K[x_1,...,x_n]$, for a field $K$: the system $S$ is *zero-dimensional* if it has finitely many solutions. It is well-known that zero-dimensionality can be decided by algorithms that rely on the construction of a Groebner basis for the ideal generated by the $m$ polynomials.

My question is, if *sufficient*, nontrivial syntactic conditions on $S$ are known by which zero-dimensionality can be so to speak "read off" from the polynomials in $S$, in particular without having to compute a Groebner basis for it.

(If helpful, restrict to 0 characteristic, algebraically closed fields $K$).

Comment: Doesn't $m=n=2$, $p_1 =x_1 + x_2, p_2 = x_2 + x_1$ satisfy your condition as stated? Maybe you mean something slightly different...

Comment: @WillSawin. Yes, thanks. I have edited to reflect better what I was conjecturing.

Comment: I still don't get it - we can take $c_1 = c_2 =2$, $q_1= x_2/2$, $q_2=x_1/2$.

Comment: Right. I have removed my conjecture altogether.

Comment: To add some context: in the specific case I am considering, $K=C(x)$ (the fraction field of complex coefficients polynomials in a distinct single variable $x$), and the equations are of the form $x_i=a_i+x\cdot p_i$, with $a_i\in C$ and $p_i\in C[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Comment: One sufficient condition, which probably doesn't apply in your case, is that $p_i$ is a polynomial only in $x_1,\dots, x_i$ and is monic in $x_i$.

Comment: I was considering the following non algebraic argument. Consider the larger field $K=C((x))$, the field of univariate Laurent series (rather than $K=C(x)$). I am now actually considering Laurent series solutions. $C((x))$ can be made a complete metric space with $d(s_1,s_2):=2^{-ord(s_1,s_2)}$, where $ord(.)$ is the least integer where the coefficients of the two series differ, and this extends to $C((x))^n$. I think one can show that the map $F$ sending ${\bf x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\in C((x))^n$ to $(...,a_i+x_i\cdot p_i({\bf x}),...)$, is a contraction. Now apply Banach fixpoint theorem.

Comment: It is a contraction on $\mathbb C[[x]]$, and your argument is completely valid for solutions there (and can be given a more algebraic flavor if desired). The issue is that it's not a contraction on $\mathbb C((x))$ because if the $x_i$ have poles then raising them to powers makes them even larger. So you need a separate argument to handle the case $x_i\notin \mathbb C[[x]]$...

Comment: Of course you are right. Any suggestion on how to handle the case $x_i\notin C[[x]]$...?

Comment: If the highest-degree terms of the polynomials are helpful (like if they have no joint roots for some reason) then that would help.

Comment: One sufficient condition is that $m = n$ and each $p_i$ has the form $p_i = x_i^{k_i} + \left(\text{terms of total degree} < k_i\right)$. This entails that $\left(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\right)$ is a Gröbner basis of the ideal with respect to the deg-lex order (by Buchberger's first criterion), and there are precisely $k_1 k_2 \cdots k_n$ standard monomials. Of course, this sufficient condition is far from necessary, but I have seen it several times in practice.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Hello, I have reconsidered this question after some time, and this seems to be a useful criterion. In case you decide to write your comment as an answer I would readily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an elaboration on my comment.

Here are two sufficient conditions:

- *Condition 1:* We have $m \geq n$, and each polynomial $p_i$ with $i \leq n$ has the form $p_i = x_i^{m_i} + \left(\text{some polynomial of degree $< m_i$}\right)$ for some nonnegative integer $m_i$.
- *Condition 2:* We have $m \geq n$, and each polynomial $p_i$ with $i \leq n$ has the form $p_i = x_i^{m_i} + \left(\text{some polynomial in the variables $x_{i+1}, x_{i+2}, \ldots, x_n$}\right)$ for some positive integer $m_i$.

Indeed, Buchberger's first criterion (Theorem 1.1.34 and Lemma 1.1.39 in [Willem de Graaf, *Computational Algebra*, 2019-09-06](http://www.science.unitn.it/%7Edegraaf/compalg/notes.pdf)) says that any set of nonzero polynomials with mutually coprime leading terms is a Gröbner basis. Using this fact, we can easily see that

- Condition 1 is sufficient, because it ensures that $\left(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\right)$ is a Gröbner basis of the ideal generated by $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ with respect to the deg-lex order (which then entails that this ideal has finite codimension, whence the ideal generated by $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m$ has finite codimension a fortiori).
- Condition 2 is sufficient, because it ensures that $\left(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\right)$ is a Gröbner basis of the ideal generated by $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ with respect to the lex order (which then entails that this ideal has finite codimension, whence the ideal generated by $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m$ has finite codimension a fortiori).